# Using jq to edit key:value in a .conf file from shell

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'm trying to write a shell script that passes an env variable into a .conf file so that I can manipulate the `log_file` and `log_level` keys programatically.

Actual file as `station.conf`

```
{
    "SX1301_conf": {
        "lorawan_public": true,
        "clksrc": 1,
        "radio_0": {
            "type": "SX1257",
            "rssi_offset": -166.0,
            "tx_enable": true,
            "antenna_gain": 0
        },
        "radio_1": {
            "type": "SX1257",
            "rssi_offset": -166.0,
            "tx_enable": false
        }
    },
    "station_conf": {
        "log_file": "stderr",
        "log_level": "DEBUG",
        /* XDEBUG,DEBUG,VERBOSE,INFO,NOTICE,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL */
        "log_size": 10000000,
        "log_rotate": 3,
        "CUPS_RESYNC_INTV": "1s"
    }
}
```

I wanted to test manually before passing shell variables so I tried `jq '".station_conf.log_level="ERROR"' station.conf`, but I keep getting errors including shell quoting errors and invalid numeric literal errors (which btw, seems to be a open bug: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/501)

Any tips on how to do this?  Ideally I'd be able to replace log_level value with a $LOG_LEVEL from my env.  Thanks!

Comment: The comment line needs to be removed from the conf file (`/* … */`) - jq does not parse json with comments. In addition, you have a double quote at the start of the jq operation string, which should not be there (`'".station_conf` should be `'.station_conf`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `invalid numeric literal error` because at least your example input is not valid json. As you can see, it contains `/* comment */`, which is not supported by jq. You have several options here.

1. keep using jq and make your input files valid json.
2. use another tool instead of jq, which support comments and/or other non-standard features.

If you choose second way, i.e. different tool, you can find some alternatives either on jq web page (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ#processing-not-quite-valid-json) or there is also `scout` (https://github.com/ABridoux/scout).

Comment: You were 100% correct, station.conf was not valid json - that was the issue. I cleaned it up and its now working.  Now I need to figure out how to actually write the change to the file.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the input is valid JSON, for robustness, you could start with:

```
jq '.station_conf.log_level="ERROR"' station.conf
```

To pass in a shell variable, consider:

```
 jq —-arg v "$LOG_LEVEL" '
   .station_conf.log_level=$v' station.conf
```